# Kendo grid dataItem not returning all columns

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a simple grid that shows id, name, and city that is a multi select (row).  I've found this quite incredible that the `dataItem` never returns the id field only name and city.  To me this seems to be a bug.  The grid is showing all the fields.  How can I get the id from the data item?

```
 opts.change = function(e) {
                    var selectedRows = ctrl.grid.select();
                    var selectedDataItems = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                        var dataItem = ctrl.grid.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                        console.log(dataItem); // never has id on it
                        selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
                    }
```

The full config stringified minus transport (opts) & change (above):

```
{
  "dataSource": {
    "pageSize": 20,
    "serverPaging": true,
    "serverFiltering": true,
    "serverSorting": true,
    "serverGrouping": false,
    "schema": {
      "total": "total",
      "data": "results",
      "model": {
        "id": "id"
      }
    }
  },
  "height": 300,
  "width": "100%",
  "filterable": {
    "extra": false
  },
  "groupable": false,
  "sortable": true,
  "pageable": true,
  "columns": [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "title": "ID",
      "hidden": false
    },
    {
      "field": "name",
      "hyperlink": "/abc/{id}",
      "icon": "bath"
    },
    {
      "field": "city"
    }
  ],
  "selectable": "multiple,row"
}
```

Here is the select test.  https://db.tt/yDLD44UNjN  I'm outputting the data item to the textbox and it is sans `id` which should be there.

Strangely enough if I output all columns (don't specify them) the id will come through.

Comment: I know there is some documentation on The Telerik site having to do with this. Can show how you define the data model? I pretty certain it has to do how the data model is defined.

Comment: No data model just using defaults.

Comment: I think that might be it I think you have to define the model, so that the data item can find/acquire the id value

Comment: Are you saying "id" is special because I"m not trying to find it, just pushing the entire dataitem into an array but in my example id doesn't exist and it should

Comment: yes, I believe that is the case, id is special. I am trying to find the telerik documentation for you

Comment: OK so you are using Datasource API. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: We have a bunch of utils that produce the grid configs. When I get back I'll get a full one and post it but just calling a read endpoint and showing all columns from it.

Comment: @DaniDev I added an answer although I don't particularly like my answer though it does work.  I'm definitely open to any other working idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post my solution, but I really would like a better one so I won't accept mine.  There seems to be some kind of conflict with a column's whose data source is `id`.  The only way I could get this to work besides changing the database which I won't do is:

1. On the grid's data callback add a new property called `_id` and set it equal to `id`.

   ```
    data: function(response) {
           for(var i=0;i<response.results.length;i++) {
              if (response.results[i].id) {
                  response.results[i]._id= response.results[i].id;
              }
           }
           return response.results;
         }
   ```

Then in the change event, setting `id` equal to `_id`.  This is really hacky and not my preferred solution but it was the only way that seemed to work.

```
       opts.change = function(e) {
                    var selectedRows = ctrl.grid.select();
                    var selectedDataItems = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                        var dataItem = ctrl.grid.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                        dataItem.id= dataItem._id;

                        selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
                    }
                    ctrl.events.change(selectedDataItems);
                }
```

I tried every combination of model, id, etc and none seemed to work.

Comment: Yes it appears that kendo dataSource does not like a non-id field being called 'id'.  I came across the same problem and renaming the field to something else fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the you define your grid. If you define your grid explicitly:
You then should define the model so that is looks something like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

        .Ajax()

        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
```

Comment: We are not using mvc binders and the grid is not defined explicitly, not model is defined just returning all in query.

Comment: Is the ID field/column displayed in the grid? If it is not displayed then the JS code may not be able to read it. Hence,  you may have to define the model so that it can read the data Item

Comment: It is displayed fine. Only issue is the data item doesn't return it. I also need to hide that column but was going to do that last.

Comment: If you are not displaying the id column, then, as we have commented in my other answer you will have to also get the selected row index and then identify the Row in the datasource.model and then get the id. It is not a bug, but it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are you using JavaScript API, then you should try to define your data model explicitly so that it looks something like this:

```
dataSource: {
    pageSize: 20,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverGrouping: false,
    schema: {

             model: { id: "id" },
             total: "total",
             data: "results"
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe I tried that too but will re confirm when I get back to my desk.  In my case it would be id:"id"

Comment: yes, the "id" field is reserved in the datasource.model. And you have to translate from you object. I will change the answer based on what you mentioned.

Comment: not certain about the schema definition syntax. Ithink you may have to define all the fields through the model?

Comment: This doesn't work.  `(dataItem)id` throws errors and the grid won't display.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean for you to use the "(dataitem)" I just put that there to let you know that you should use whatever the id is called in your datamodel. I think you have mentioned it is "id" in which case you would use: model: { id: "id" },   if it was called foo_id the you would use model: {id: "foo_id"}

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I posted the config in my answer.  Unfortunately none of these work

Comment: See my comment below regarding not displaying the id  column
As we discussed in my other answer, if you are not displaying the grid's id column/field, then, you will need to get the selected row and then iterate through the Data.Source to get the row (based on index or some other unique field) and then get the id that way.

Comment: I understand but your solution when displaying it doesn't work unfortunately.  The column id is being removed unless I remove all the column definitions and then it works fine.

Comment: "unless I remove all the column definitions and then it works fine..."
hey, sounds like you are on the right track. hopefully my answers/ comments were helpful?  Let me know if I can offer any other help. Cheers

Comment: It doesn't help or really address my issue.  If I don't pass in column defintions to the grid it will show the id when getting the selected items.  If I pass in column definitions it strips out the id even if the id is defined as a column defintion and on the model.  I need to pass in column definitions.

Comment: I read it before.  According to that id:"id" should work.  It doesn't. I will try to add some public examples demonstrating the issue.

Comment: seems like you have implemented this (model definition) into our solution?   "model": {
        "id": "id"
      }
would have been gracious of you to acknowledge the help.

Comment: It didn't do anything.  My final solution has no model in it.  I was forced to add a field called _id that I'd populate before the grid removes the id field via the data callback.  None of the solutions presented here worked otherwise I would have accepted one of them.

Comment: did you not change your question to include the model  after I posted my answer? "model": {
        "id": "id"
      }

Comment: I did and it didn't work.  My final solution has no model in it, I posted my answer on how I fixed it.

Comment: No worries, Bro! your solution is doing something similar to what I had recommended in my comments which is your id field/column is not a viewable accessible. You are hiding the id field in in a new data item.field (_id) and then retrieving it and recreating the id field which is not being displayed. 

Good Job! and good luck!